# adding a footer to the page in an HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, httpresponse

I could use late events such as EndRequest and put inside Response.Write but this way whatever I'm adding would come after the  /html tag and the HTML won't be well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad practice to use the HttpModule for page footer. This can lead to possible errors with UpdatePanels, and possible with other controls on randomly pages - especial if you try to add controls.

Also its probably delay the load of all pages and eat a lot of memory reading the page and append at the end strings on every single request.

**Use a master page !**. Its very simple and the correct way.

More to read: [Creating a Layout Using Master Pages](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/masterpages/default.aspx)